# Angularjs Modules - Packaging Directives and Their Controllers

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller, angularjs-module

I have the following javascript code and i ran into a issue:

**My .js file**

```
angular.module('MyApp',['ngMaterial','ngMessages'])
.controller('MainCtrl',['$mdDialog',function($mdDialog'){
this.openDialog = openDialog;

function openDialog() {
....... my codes ...... 
    }
)])
.controller('SubCtrl',function($scope){

   my codes.

})

.directive('test',function(){
    return {
        controller: 'MainCtrl' ,
        scope: { } ,
        templateUrl: 'Button.html'
     }
})
```

Currently,  I am using the controller 'MainCtrl' in my directive. But is it possible to put all the controller into the directive and still make it run as per normal usage??

what I want in my final **.js File**

```
.directive('test',function(){

my controllers all here <-- unsure of the syntax.

}
```

Comment: You can use the controller any times.

Comment: i am unsure of the syntax to put the controller and directives together

Comment: @Sai Maybe you could give me some advice?

Comment: How you have written is the correct way to do it. What you want to do in excess.

Comment: @Sai My assignment needs me to put it together. So I have to figure a way out

Comment: its for reusability of the directive as it might be used in another program , so and i would need the controller so i need to combine the controller and the directive together

Comment: Do you want to put the controller in the directive? Not out side?

Comment: Correct. I need to put all the controller inside the directive. But i need help with the syntax to put controller into the directive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In the end i would need to package my directive into a .js file so that my classmates can use it just by calling the directive name and putting in the .js file of the directive

To package the directive and controller into a single module:

### sai.js

```
angular.module("saiModule",[]);

angular.module("saiModule").controller("saiController",function() {
    //Put controller code here
});

angular.module("saiModule").directive("saiDirective", function() {
    //Put directive code here
});
```

Then classmates use it by adding the module as a dependency to their apps:

### JS

```
angular.module("myApp", ["saiModule"]);
```

### HTML

```
<sai-directive></sai-directive>
```

Services, filters, providers, constants, etc. can also be added to the module.

For more information, see [AngularJS Module API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/angular.Module).

Comment: thank you for the answer ! i just want to clarify , is this the only way to do this ?? or is there another way to package it too? just a question ! @gerogeawg

Comment: For more elaborate ways to do it, check out [Johnpapa's Opinionated Angular Style Guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do like this by putting function inside of directive:

```
.directive('test',function(){
    return {
        controller: function('$mdDialog'){
            this.openDialog = openDialog;

            function openDialog() {
                ....... my codes ...... 
            } 
        },
        scope: { } ,
        templateUrl: 'Button.html'
     }
})
```

Comment: is it possible to give a naming convention to the controller and is it possible to add multiple controller ?

Comment: No, you cant use multiple controllers. But you can apply multiple directives. What do you mean by `naming convention`.

Comment: can i initialize controller in my directive?? i only need to call one controller in this directive and have more other controllers just initialized in directive?

Comment: You don't need to initialise explicitly. The directive on which you applied controller automatically get initialised.

Comment: my assignments needs me to design a directive that can be used by any body in the class. In the end i would need to package my directive into a .js file so that my classmates can use it just by calling the directive name and putting in the .js file of the directive. Am i on the righr track ? @Sai